# Is it possible to integrate Maven Surefire with a custom testing framework?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

From the `Surefire` documentation I understand that it can auto-detect basically only JUnit & TestNG. Is it possible to connect it to another testing framework?

Would appreciate links to any samples.

Comment: I think you need to specify *which* other framework and what it does.

Comment: It's my own test framework. And what it does... I guess testing. :) Same as JUnit + some more stuff. I am trying to understand if I can make it work with Surefire or it's better to develop my own Maven plugin.

Comment: What is the purpose of your own test framework?